# I can't find the answer to this Homogeneous equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation?

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2xy}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right)$$,lets do $$u=\frac{y}{x}$$ then $$ux=y$$ and $$y'=u'x+u$$

Comment: When I finished my typing then I saw you post your answer @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner If you think it's possibly duplicated then let me know I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following let $u = \frac{y}{x} $

Comment: Hmm, maybe better to divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ and then make that substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^{2}\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^{2}}\right)}{2xy}=\frac{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}{2\frac{y}{x}}
$ Can you go from here$?$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} ~~~~(1)$$
Let $y=vx \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x \frac{dv}{dx}.$
Then
$$v+xv'=\frac{1+v^2}{2v} \implies  \int \frac{2v}{1-v^2}= \frac{dx}{x}
 \implies -\ln (1-v^2)= \ln Cx \implies Cx(1-v^2)=1.$$
Finally, the solution of the ODE (1) is $$x^2-y^2=Dx,$$
where $D$ is a constant,

Comment: I didn't understand why integral of 1/x is lnCx instead of lnx+c

Comment: @FranklinAraujo it's the same $\ln (Cx)=\ln(x)+\ln C=\ln(x)+K$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2xy}$$
$$2xydy=x^2dx+y^2dx$$
$$xdy^2-y^2dx=x^2dx$$
$$\frac {xdy^2-y^2dx}{x^2}=dx$$
$$d\left (\frac {y^2}x \right) =dx$$
After integration:
$$y^2=x^2+Cx$$